# How can I change the result of this code to save attachments and not messages?

Tags: vba, outlook, directory, outlook-addin

I need to make a macro for outlook that will enable a user to select certain emails and then extract the attachments from those emails into a folder on the hard drive which is automatically created and named using the subject of the email and the date the email was received using formatted: (ddmmyyyy - SUBJECT) with the attachment inside of the folder.

I have tried making using C# and wasn't very efficient in what I was able to accomplish.

VBA seems more practical for what I'm trying to do and the code that I have right now does almost exactly what I need. However, it saves the whole email as a message to my directory and not just the attachment.

```
    Option Explicit
'This macro not required for Rule script
Sub Save_Messages()
Dim olItem As MailItem
Dim fPath As String
    fPath = BrowseForFolder(CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) & "\desktop\") & Chr(92)
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        If olItem.Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then
            SaveMessage olItem, fPath
            DoEvents
        End If
    Next olItem
    Set olItem = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub SaveMessage(olItem As MailItem, fPath As String)
'Sub SaveMessage(olItem As MailItem) 'Alternative for rule script
'Const fPath As String = "C:\Path\" 'Set Path - required for rule script
Dim Fname As String
Dim dtDate As Date
    dtDate = olItem.ReceivedTime
    Fname = olItem.Subject
    Fname = Fname & " - " & "[" & olItem.SenderName + "]"
    Fname = Format(dtDate, "yymmddKT", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                   vbUseSystem) & " - " & Fname & " - {" & _
                   Format(dtDate, "hh.mm", _
                          vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                          vbUseSystem) & "}"
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")
    SaveUnique olItem, fPath, Fname
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Private Function SaveUnique(oItem As Object, _
                            strPath As String, _
                            strFileName As String)
Dim lngF As Long
Dim lngName As Long
    lngF = 1
    lngName = Len(strFileName)
    Do While FileExists(strPath & strFileName & ".msg") = True
        strFileName = Left(strFileName, lngName) & "(" & lngF & ")"
        lngF = lngF + 1
    Loop
    oItem.SaveAs strPath & strFileName & ".msg"
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

Private Function FileExists(filespec) As Boolean
Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If fso.FileExists(filespec) Then
        FileExists = True
    Else
        FileExists = False
    End If
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Function
End Function

'Following function not required for Rule script
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
Dim ShellApp As Object
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
                   BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
    End Select
    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function
```

I am expecting to be able to click on my selected emails and click the macro which will in turn open a pop up directory that I can choose where my folder will be and have it save the attachments to that location with the attachments inside of the named folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm sure we can do better but here try this.....*

```
Option Explicit
'This macro not required for Rule script

Dim FldrName As String

Sub Save_Messages()
    Dim olItem As MailItem
    Dim fPath As String
    Dim Atmt As Outlook.Attachment


    fPath = BrowseForFolder(CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE")) & "\desktop\") & Chr(92)
    For Each olItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.selection
        If olItem.Class = OlObjectClass.olMail Then

            For Each Atmt In olItem.Attachments
                DoEvents

                SaveMessage olItem, fPath

                Atmt.SaveAsFile FldrName & "\" & Atmt.DisplayName

            Next

        End If
    Next olItem

    Set olItem = Nothing
lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub SaveMessage(olItem As MailItem, fPath As String)
'Sub SaveMessage(olItem As MailItem) 'Alternative for rule script
'Const fPath As String = "C:\Path\" 'Set Path - required for rule script
Dim Fname As String
Dim dtDate As Date
    dtDate = olItem.ReceivedTime
    Fname = olItem.Subject

    Fname = Fname
    Fname = Format(dtDate, "yymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
                   vbUseSystem) & " - " & Fname
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(41), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58) & Chr(40), "")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(34), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(42), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(47), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(58), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(60), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(62), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(63), "-")
    Fname = Replace(Fname, Chr(124), "-")


    Debug.Print fPath, Fname

    FldrName = fPath & Fname

    Debug.Print FldrName

    CreateDir FldrName

lbl_Exit:
    Exit Sub
End Sub


'Following function not required for Rule script
Function BrowseForFolder(Optional OpenAt As Variant) As Variant
Dim ShellApp As Object
    Set ShellApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application"). _
                   BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0, OpenAt)

    On Error Resume Next
    BrowseForFolder = ShellApp.self.Path
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set ShellApp = Nothing
    Select Case Mid(BrowseForFolder, 2, 1)
        Case Is = ":"
            If Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = ":" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Is = "\"
            If Not Left(BrowseForFolder, 1) = "\" Then GoTo Invalid
        Case Else
            GoTo Invalid
    End Select
    Exit Function

Invalid:
    BrowseForFolder = False
End Function

Private Function CreateDir(FldrPath As String)
    Dim Elm As Variant
    Dim CheckPath As String

    CheckPath = ""
    For Each Elm In Split(FldrPath, "\")
        CheckPath = CheckPath & Elm & "\"

        If Len(Dir(CheckPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir CheckPath
            Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Created"
        End If

        Debug.Print CheckPath & " Folder Exist"
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Is there any way I could also add function to open the last folder saved to when running the macro to save a new attachment?

Comment: Cool you posted new question- I will look at it later to see if I can fix it @Camnaz

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are saving the message, not only the attachments. Add the following line to your DIM section:

```vb
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments, i as Integer, lngCount as Integer
```

Then in your `For Each` section, delete these (2) lines `sName = sName + ".msg"; msg.SaveAs sName, olMsg` and replace with the following:

```
Set objAttachments = msg.Attachments
lngCount = objAttachments.Count

If lngCount > 0 Then
    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
        objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile sName & lngCount
    Next i
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, I grabbed the code from my first file. This is the one I am actually using.

Comment: This one is working similar to the other one. I wouldn't know how to go about performing this same action on this code though.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. This code saves attachment